# Not able to run flutter application in simulator (iOS 15)

Tags: xcode, flutter, ios-simulator, ios15

I have update flutter version from 1.x to 2.8.x and now I am trying to run application in Xcode 13.1 and Simulator iOS 15. I am facing this error. `'mobileffmpeg/LogDelegate.h' file not found` and `Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code` I tried some available solutions but it won't work for me.

I am using latest cocoa pod version `1.11.3`

Error-Log (After performing flutter clean and flutter pub get and pod install in iOS)

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ewlkrnytkuoiywhfslyuauileapw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobile-ffmpeg-https.build/Script-4C68ADEB2D24F6C2D2249598537085F9.sh: 
line 2: /Users/username/Documents/spieler_coach part 2/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/mobile-ffmpeg-https/mobile-ffmpeg-https-xcframeworks.sh: Permission denied
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
CompileC /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ewlkrnytkuoiywhfslyuauileapw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/webview_flutter_wkwebview.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FlutterWebView.o /Users/username/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'webview_flutter_wkwebview' from project 'Pods')
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
Could not build the application for the simulator.
```

Comment: Which CocoaPods version you used?Try to Upgrading CocoaPods version

Comment: My current CocoaPods version is 1.11.3

Comment: Are you using `ffmpeg_kit_flutter` or `flutter_ffmpeg`?

Comment: Are you using ffmpeg_kit_flutter or flutter_ffmpeg?

Comment: Yes, I am using flutter_ffmpeg. after checking other solutions, I comment that and now error is 'addPluginScript' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer.

Comment: make sure that you are using the latest version of cocoapods. Some versions have issues with newer xcframework bundles. could you share your flutter version

Comment: flutter version is 2.8.1

Comment: can you attach the logs?

Comment: If you create a new “hello world” flutter app does it run?  If so, then you should be able to follow the same logic adding more components from the real app  one-by-one to narrow down the problem even more and make your question more precise

Comment: I cannot add one-by-one component in new project, because my current project is large one. So I copy - paste same pub spec.yaml ni new "hello world" program - this one is working fine. but issue with the original one

Answer (score 0):

When you upgrade your flutter version some libs can not work anymore. Have you  know meaning of ^ yet? For example: you're using lib abc in version 5.10 like this
`abc: ^5.1.0` and abc has other version `5.2.0`, ...`5.9.0` and `6.0.0`. If you use `^` that means version range is from `5.1.0 to 5.9.0`. Maybe it has issue in ver 5.9.0. Moreover, sometimes the cause is not your library but its dependency. The `abc` lib uses `xyz` inside then it uses higher version that conflict with your flutter version.

- So solution here is:

  - Try fix hard version of all libraries, remove using `^`: `abc: 5.1.0`
  - If problem comes from dependency of your lib such as `xyz`. Check your `xyz` ver from `pubspec.lock` then add more package `xyz` into pubspec.yaml with compatible version.

**Update:**
You seems get issue with package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg, please check Readme at section label:

```
2.1.2 iOS (Flutter >= 2.x) then replace two lines below:

def flutter_install_ios_plugin_pods(ios_application_path = nil)
↓
def flutter_install_plugin_pods(application_path = nil, relative_symlink_dir, platform)

plugin_pods = flutter_parse_plugins_file(plugins_file)
↓
plugin_pods = flutter_parse_plugins_file(plugins_file, platform)
```

Moreover, because the package was discontinued. You should change to https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter

Comment: I remove that ^ sign from flutter_ffmpeg package. issue is not solved yet

Comment: Have you try remove `pubspec.lock` and `flutter clean` yet?, maybe try remove project then clone again, is it occured?

Moreover, can you provide additional logs? This problem in both android and ios or just ios?

Comment: Yes, I try that way. Also this issue is occur only for iOS simulator, for android its working

Comment: Please provide logs when run `pod repo update` and `pod install` ? Remember remove Podfile.lock before run

Comment: Is it package you use? It's discontinued :(((
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg

Comment: I've just update answer for you, I think you missed update PodFile when upgrade Flutter from 1.x to 2.x

Comment: Ok, Let me check. Also I have add log in question description